# AKS - when cpu usage is at the maximum value, requests are dropped

Tags: python, kubernetes, flask, azure-aks, docker-container

In Azure kubernetes services I deploy pods containing a Flask API. Each pod gets assigned 500 millicores of cpu resources.

When I run many requests at once, the 500m limit is reached for all pods. The autoscaler scales up the pods, but this takes a while. While there are no pods available, requests are ignored and left pending.

I started solving this by implementing a WSGI like Waitress to keep the requests in a queue. But now I am wondering if this is the way to go, because the WSGI will be in the container that runs Flask. And since that container is on its maximum cpu, would adding a request queue even change anything if it is unreachable?

I also thought about creating the queue by hand. With this I mean: storing the requests flask receives and then executing them when there is free cpu. Again though I run into the problem that the requests would not even reach this handmade queue.

Important to know is that I ran the container locally in dockerdesktop and it was able to handle all the requests I sent it. It took a while to process them all, but none got an error and none were ignored.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to scale out, before any limits are reached? If limits are reached, have you tried to scale out earlier?

Comment: I have 6 pods running by default, this can handle 30 requests at once. If I send 40 requests though, only 34 will be handled. I am using a horizontal pod autoscaler (hpa), and it scales up when 40% of cpu is used. The problem is not in the hpa not working, it can go to 40 pods. The problem is that while it is scaling up, many requests are being dropped. This is in bursty traffic, so if 30 requests are made twice, five minutes from eachother, there would be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

It can take a few minutes for the autoscaler to add new nodes and for the nodes to be `Ready`. The default [autoscaler profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/hybrid/work-with-autoscaler-profiles#profile-settings) is not the most aggressive, so you might want to configure the `new-pod-scale-up-delay` and `scan-interval`.

I'm sure you're already using the Horizontal Pod Auto-scaler and having a number of replicas, however perhaps you need to be running more nodes or bigger nodes to cope with the baseline demand.

I think you've got a few options, starting simply with looking at [Virtual Nodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/virtual-nodes) for faster scaling.
All the way up to looking at buffering requests through using a queue (and potentially [KEDA](https://keda.sh/) for earlier scaling).

If workload is unpredictable-burst and scaling time is the most important consideration, then Virtual Nodes could well be suitable.

Another thought is considering a timeout and retry mechanism for the clients creating these requests.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I will look into all of these. I have some questions about the queue. Where would the queue be put? In another containter in the pods? A pod with a different configuration? is it something in AKS? Do you have any documentation I could read?

Comment: Queue architecture is going to be down to preference. 
You could keep it in-cluster, but then you'll need to worry about state. 
An easy option would be to use the Azure Service Bus service, for a more managed experience. Although this does introduce another distinct cost into your solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "then you'll need to worry about state"?

Comment: Most queues don't just function by storing the messages in memory. They'll write them down to storage (state). In the case of Kubernetes, this increases the complexity.

Comment: I see, do you have some examples of these queues? Do you mean something like Celery? Gunicorn? NGINX?

Comment: Celery, Gunicorn, and NGINX are not queues in the traditional sense, although they do have some queue-like functionality.

Celery is a task queue that is often used in conjunction with a message broker such as RabbitMQ or Redis. 

Gunicorn is a Python WSGI HTTP server that is often used to serve web applications. 

NGINX is a web server and reverse proxy that is often used to balance incoming traffic across multiple backend servers. 

I'd suggest that if you want a queue,  use Azure Service Bus for the time being. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/products/service-bus

Comment: I will look into using Azure Service Bus, Thank you for the explanation! If you don't mind would you still like to explain what you meant by "You could keep it in-cluster"? Or is the Azure Service Bus an example of that?

Comment: By In-Cluster i mean using an open source queue system like RabbitMQ that will be installed into the AKS Cluster alongside your workload.

Comment: Great! So, I would put these in the container with the Flask API then? What would happen if the max cpu of the pod is reached, will the RabbitMQ queue still be reachable?

Comment: Adding a queue is a bigger architectural change. I'd suggest starting with Virtual Nodes which could well be an easier option.